# Laravel 5.5 with MySQL 8.0.11: 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've just installed MySQL `8.0.11`, transferred my app's database into it, and changed the Laravel database settings to use the new one. Now every time I try to log in I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1231 (42000):
Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
```

I tried to set `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` manually:

```
set global sql_mode="..., NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, ...";
```

But I get the same error. How could I solve the problem and run Laravel `5.5` with MySQL `8.0.11`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The next release of Laravel 5.5 will add support for MySQL 8.0: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24038

**UPDATE**: Laravel 5.5.41 has been released.

Answer (score 59):

your laravel connexion (config / database.php) should be such that:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 15):

Add the following on each of your MySQL connections:

```
'modes' => [
     'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
     'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
     'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
     'NO_ZERO_DATE',
     'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
     'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
],
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 8.0 does not support NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MySQL 8.0.18 on Windows Wampserver and adding the below to database.php for Laravel

```
'modes'  => [
        'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8.0 at this Moment(as today) does not support NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
you should find and replace in your backup:  "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER," by Space

this way Backup from 5.7 will restore ok in 8.0

Answer (score 1):

How to fix laravel NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
code for database.php

---

```
mode => [
'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
'NO_ZERO_DATE',
'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
]
```